# How only one tile is showed in openlayers map when I load tile using javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Recently, I was doing a job about loading the tiles into the openlayers map. But the tiles showed in maps puzzled me. When I load only one tile the map shows infinite number of this tile. But the result is not compatible to me. What can I do to achieve that only one tile is showed in the openlayers map? I'm glad for any request.
The code is showed as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tiles-test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    urls: ['../1.png', '../2.png'],
                    projection: 'EPSG:3857'

                }),
            }),
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: ({
                collapsible: false
            })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform(
                [30, 30], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 10
        })

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result showed in map is as following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnEfS.png)

Answer (score 2):

The XYZ source is a *tile* source, and not intened for single images. It uses *url patterns* to load the tiles.

Look at the url/urls parameter [in the docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html):

> Must include {x}, {y} or {-y}, and {z} placeholders. A
> {?-?} template pattern, for example subdomain{a-f}.domain.com, may be
> used instead of defining each one separately in the urls option.

The XYZ's [TileGrid](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html) defines how the grid looks like. Since you did not specify it, it used the default configuration and applied the (static) url you defined to every map tile.

If you just want to place a static image on the map, use ImageStatic ([docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageStatic.html), [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html))